# Dharmashastras used in Valmiki Ramayana & Mahabharta

Tags: mahabharata, ramayana, dharma-shastras, nitishastra

Dharma/Niti shastras were used in Ram Rajyam and other popular kingdoms in Mahabharata and Ramayana.